# How to find periodicity of time series spanning micro time units?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a time series, in which the time unit is millisecs, and the series
has about 3000 entries. I am trying to find out the seasonality
of this series, eg to detect any periodic glitches in the data. The data is
represented as a pandas dataframe.

I tried using the seasonal_decompose() method from statsmodel,like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Sample_data.csv',index_col=0)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
print(data.head())
##                              Sample_values
## Dates    
## 1970-01-01 05:30:00.000000   0.466812
## 1970-01-01 05:30:00.016667   0.218692
## 1970-01-01 05:30:00.033333   0.938067
## 1970-01-01 05:30:00.050000   0.480025
## 1970-01-01 05:30:00.066667   0.915175
print(type(data))
##  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
result = seasonal_decompose(data, model='additive')
fig = result.plot()
```

But it results in the following error:

```
ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index with a freq not set to None
```

However, if I use the same code with a dataset whose x-axis units are in months (eg downloaded from https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/AirPassengers.csv ), then I dont get any errors and I get the 4 plots from seasonal_decompose() as expected.

So how can I detect seasonality patterns for my kind of data, which spans only over
few hours?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a defined `freq` for the datetime index.

Using the following:

```
                            sample_values
1970-01-01 05:30:00.000000       0.466812
1970-01-01 05:30:00.016667       0.218692
1970-01-01 05:30:00.033333       0.938067
1970-01-01 05:30:00.050000       0.480025
1970-01-01 05:30:00.066667       0.915175
```

The frequency is currently `None`

```
In [1]: print df.index
DatetimeIndex([       '1970-01-01 05:30:00', '1970-01-01 05:30:00.016667',
               '1970-01-01 05:30:00.033333', '1970-01-01 05:30:00.050000',
               '1970-01-01 05:30:00.066667'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

And Pandas `infer_freq` function is unable to detect it:

```
In [2]: print pd.infer_freq(df.index)
None
```

If you know what the frequency of the data should be, you can reindex to this frequency. However, this is difficult with your index, as the repeating decimals in the timestamp need to be rounded to some defined interval. This gets close:

```
In [3]: df_freq = df.resample('.000001S').ffill().reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0],df.index[-1],freq='0.016667S'))

In [4]: print df_freq
                            sample_values
1970-01-01 05:30:00.000000       0.466812
1970-01-01 05:30:00.016667       0.218692
1970-01-01 05:30:00.033334       0.938067
1970-01-01 05:30:00.050001       0.480025

In [5]: print df_freq.index
DatetimeIndex([       '1970-01-01 05:30:00', '1970-01-01 05:30:00.016667',
               '1970-01-01 05:30:00.033334', '1970-01-01 05:30:00.050001'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='16667U')
```

Now you have a defined `freq`. Try that on your full dataset, and see if the `seasonal_decompose()` will run. However, the timestamps will likely become inaccurate over long lengths of time.

You can also try something like this:

```
In [6]: df_freq = df.resample('.000001S').interpolate().resample('.005S').first()

In [7]: print df_freq
                         sample_values
1970-01-01 05:30:00.000       0.466812
1970-01-01 05:30:00.005       0.392377
1970-01-01 05:30:00.010       0.317943
1970-01-01 05:30:00.015       0.243508
1970-01-01 05:30:00.020       0.362558
1970-01-01 05:30:00.025       0.578380
1970-01-01 05:30:00.030       0.794201
1970-01-01 05:30:00.035       0.892255
1970-01-01 05:30:00.040       0.754845
1970-01-01 05:30:00.045       0.617435
1970-01-01 05:30:00.050       0.480025
1970-01-01 05:30:00.055       0.610567
1970-01-01 05:30:00.060       0.741110
1970-01-01 05:30:00.065       0.871652
```

This has `freq='5L'`, and uses linear interpolation to approximate the trend of your original data with a regular frequency index. You can experiment with `.005S` for the second downsampling frequency to get a higher or lower frequency if you desire.